# Degree of morphism of quotient of upper half-plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, covering-spaces

Recall that SL$_2(\mathbf R)$ acts on the complex upper half-plane $\mathbf H$. Let $\Gamma$ be a finite index subgroup of SL$_2(\mathbf Z)$.  Then there is the quotient $Y_\Gamma = \Gamma \backslash \mathbf H$ which maps to the curve $Y(1)$ via the inclusion.

What is the degree of this map? Is it just the index of $\Gamma$ in SL$_2(\mathbf Z)$? If not, is the degree of this branched cover $Y_\Gamma \to Y(1)$  bounded by the index of $\Gamma$  in SL$_2(\mathbf Z)$?

Comment: yes, it's $[SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma]$.

Comment: That's what I thought. But is there a clear explanation?

Comment: for most points the group acts freely, so you can count the number of points in preimage of a point directly.

Answer (score 1):

By $Y(1)$, I'm assuming you mean the orbifold $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbf{H}$. In fact, the center of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $-I$, which acts trivially on $\mathbf{H}$ (so it's $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ that acts faithfully on $\mathbf{H}$). Given a subgroup $\Gamma < SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, let $\pm\Gamma=\Gamma\cup -\Gamma$.  The curve $Y_\Gamma$ will be the same as the curve $Y_{\pm \Gamma}$, and the degree of the cover $Y_\Gamma\to Y(1)$ will then be $[SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\pm \Gamma]$. If $-I\in \Gamma$, then $\Gamma=\pm \Gamma$, and otherwise, $[\pm \Gamma:\Gamma]=2$, in which case the degree is $[SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma]/2$.